# Is "Organization-Wide Email Footer" available as metadata?

Tags: email, deployment, metadata

We use "Organization-Wide Email Footer" functionality. Is it available as **metadata** to move changes to higher environments or this should be done as a post-deployment step?

Note: I couldn't find any reference to it in [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/58).